# File sync application like dropbox for Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, synchronization, dropbox

I'm struggling with a bit problem. I have the past days been thinking about how nice it would be with a dropbox kind of app that could keep a folder synched with my amazon s3 back end. Sadly, not really tried alot out, but from reading i havent been able to find any apps that features exactly what dropbox do.

I dont wanna mount a network drive and such.

I'm quite sure that i would be able to write a little app myself that could upload and download files from amazon s3 bucket, but thinking about it lead me to a dilemma.

From my understanding dropbox does like svn do, it only commit its changes. So are anyone able to give some input on the stuff behind the scene?

If i change a file on my system, how can it check the changes vs this file and the one on the remote site without first downloading the remote file?

If anyone know of a client that works great and like dropbox, feel free to share aswell. I found that ubuntu one have a great system working with cheaper prices then dropbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I am not allowed to talk about my client here, but I can tell you two things. First, it is not at all easy to make a dropbox like app, it will take months to make something decent. Second, you can use the object Etag to see if it has changed locally. Etag is basically a checksum and you can easily calculate it on the client.

Comment: I do not dough that it will take months to make something great. But with a few days it should be possible to make some simple upload when changed and download when changed :) But as you say, it should not be a problem to watch if there are local changes :) I just wondered how the diff from remote vs local is done without downloading the hole remote file all the time.

Comment: @PoulK.Sørensen As an idea: What if whenever you upload a file, you also send the hash of the file contents. Then when you check the remote server you can compare local hashes to already existing remote hashes and download or overwrite the ones that have changed. Hash based comparison is slow though, for a toy project I wonder if date modified and file name is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I built something similar after seeing this question. This is not THE solution, but a good place to start

http://sharathprabhal.tumblr.com/post/68737134239/an-auto-syncing-nobackend-cloud-storage-app-using-only

https://github.com/sharathprabhal/NBS3Sync

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly old question, but [S3FS](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) + rsync is a perfect replacement for dropbox. I'm making an assumption that you have the skill to setup a fuse based filesystem on Linux.